# Java generates the WSDL but cant access it using ?wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

I need my web service class to return an array of the following customer class which has an array in itself.

When create the web service the wsdl will be created but when I try to access it using its url it shows the following error.

Following error will be shown when I add ?wsdl to address

> AXIS error
>
> Could not generate WSDL!
>
> There is no SOAP service at this location

Following Error will be shown when I do not add ?wsdl to address

```
AXIS error

No service is available at this URL
```

My Customer class

```
package myclasses;

public class customer {
private String name;
private int age;
private int[] rankings;

public customer(){
    //Any initializations here.
}

public customer(String n, int a) {
    this.name = n;
    this.age = a;
    rankings = new int[2];
    rankings[0] = 1;
    rankings[1] = 2;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

............Rest of setter and getters goes here .............

}
```

My Web service class

```
     package services;

import myclasses.customer;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding; 

@WebService (name="Hellos", 
targetNamespace="http://localhost:8081/Mywebservice2/services/Hellos")  
@SOAPBinding  
(  
      style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC,  
      use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,  
      parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED  
 )  
public class Hellos {

    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult(name="name",partName="name") String getName(){
        return "Jack";
    }
    
    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult (name="customers",partName="customers") customer[] mycustomers() {
        customer[] cus = new customer[2];
        cus[0] = new customer("Jack", 28);
        cus[1] = new customer("Alex", 29);
        return cus;
        
    }
}
```

My wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://services" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://services" xmlns:intf="http://services" xmlns:tns1="http://myclasses" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://services" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://myclasses"/>
   <element name="getName">
    <complexType/>
   </element>
   <element name="getNameResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="getNameReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="mycustomers">
    <complexType/>
   </element>
   <element name="mycustomersResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="mycustomersReturn" type="tns1:customer"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://myclasses" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <complexType name="customer">
    <sequence>
     <element name="age" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="getNameResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getNameResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="mycustomersResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:mycustomersResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="mycustomersRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:mycustomers" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getNameRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getName" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="Hellos">

      <wsdl:operation name="getName">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getNameRequest" name="getNameRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getNameResponse" name="getNameResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="mycustomers">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:mycustomersRequest" name="mycustomersRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:mycustomersResponse" name="mycustomersResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="HellosSoapBinding" type="impl:Hellos">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="getName">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="getNameRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="getNameResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="mycustomers">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="mycustomersRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="mycustomersResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="HellosService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:HellosSoapBinding" name="Hellos">

 

        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8081/Mywebservice2/services/Hellos"/>
    
           </wsdl:port>
    
        </wsdl:service>
    
     </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: @Telthien, thanks for comment but whats the problem I do not get you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Comment improperly placed. Ignore it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The value type "myclasses.customer" used via the service class "services.Hellos" **does not have a public default constructor**

Just use this in customer class.

```
public customer()
{
  //Any initializations here.
}
```

Comment: @Srinvas, thanks for reply, I added the default constructor but the generated wsdl file shows the following : AXIS error

Could not generate WSDL!

There is no SOAP service at this location

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your webservice definition

```
@SOAPBinding
(
style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,
use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED
)
```

Comment: I copied it before my method declaration and after the @webmethod, but the eclipse says "multiple markers at this line".

Comment: it needs to be defined at service level i.e on top of @WebService

Comment: alternative approach adn better explanation here - http://oreilly.com/catalog/javasoap/chapter/ch05.html

Comment: Also is it possible for your design to user List of objects instead of Array of objects ?

Comment: Yes I just need a list of objects, it does not matter if its a list,  array or any other data type.

Comment: modify your code to return ArrayList public ArrayList myCustomers() , in your method body add customers to ArrayList and return that ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.

Solution : In my case, I was using Axis 1.4 and was deploying the application on tomcat. However, for some reason the generated server-config.wsdd was not getting packaged in the war and hence was not getting deployed on tomcat. Once, I ensured this is happening, it started working fine for me.